# What makes a query slow with very few rows in `EXPLAIN`?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

My query crosses 4 tables over well-indexed `JOIN`'s with a maximum of ~500 rows. Yet the query regularly takes several minutes to complete.

What am I missing?

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    homework.id AS homework_id,
    homework.description
FROM homework
JOIN student_homework_assn 
  ON homework.id = student_homework_assn.homework_id
JOIN class_student_assn 
  ON student_homework_assn.student_id = class_student_assn.student_id
JOIN class 
  ON class_student_assn.class_id = class.id
WHERE homework.grade IS NULL
  AND homework.homework_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
  AND class.class_status_id = 2
LIMIT 1000;

*** row 1 ***
          table:  class
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY,class_status_id,class_multi_1
            key:  class_status_id
        key_len:  4
            ref:  const
           rows:  539
          Extra:  Using index
*** row 2 ***
          table:  class_student_assn
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  student_id_2,student_id
            key:  student_id_2
        key_len:  4
            ref:  class.id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using index
*** row 3 ***
          table:  student_homework_assn
           type:  ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY,idx_homework_id,idx_student_id
            key:  idx_student_id
        key_len:  8
            ref:  class_student_assn.student_id
           rows:  262
          Extra:  Using index
*** row 4 ***
          table:  homework
           type:  eq_ref
  possible_keys:  PRIMARY,id,homework_date
            key:  PRIMARY
        key_len:  8
            ref:  student_homework_assn.homework_id
           rows:  1
          Extra:  Using where
```

Brief Table Descriptions:

```
Table                   # Rows
homework                200M
student_homework_assn    25M
class_student_assn        2k
class                     3k
```

Where should I look next to reduce this query's run time?

Comment: `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
  AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -0 DAY)` => `BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) 
  AND NOW()`

Comment: Thanks @lad2025 for the comment and edit. I tried both `homework_date BETWEEN ... AND NOW()` and `homework_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)`. Both results are equally long (200-300s!), and similar to the original query time. What next?

Comment: Of the three, `homework_date > DATE_ADD...` is consistently faster, but still way to slow for production (never under 90s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated well-indexed joins but I don't think that is accurate from what I am getting from the explain and the keys.  Your keys appear to be single column indexes which is not optimized.  Having composite keys (col1, col2, col3) for example would help.

I rewrote your query with aliases to simplify some.  Also formatted for myself to visually see the explicit relationships between the tables.  I also moved the class status to the JOIN component to the class table.

```
SELECT
      H.id AS homework_id,
      H.description
   FROM 
      Homework H
         JOIN student_homework_assn SHA
            ON H.id = SHA.homework_id
            JOIN class_student_assn CSA
               ON SHA.student_id = CSA.student_id
               JOIN class C
                  ON CSA.class_id = C.id
                 AND C.class_status_id = 2
   WHERE 
          H.grade IS NULL
      AND H.homework_date > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
   LIMIT 
      1000;
```

I would suggest the following composite indexes on your respective tables and why...

```
table: Homework        
index: (grade, homework_date, id)   or  (homework_date, grade, id)
```

the grade and homework are available to optimize the WHERE clause by specific date and grade respectively... however, it ALSO includes the ID used to join to the student homework association table.  This way, the database does not have to query every record at the page level to qualify which ones meet the minimum criteria.  The ID is also included as joining to the next level to the student_homework_assn table.

```
table: Student_Homework_Assn  
index: (homework_id, student_id)
```

homework ID to match the previous table of homework, but then the student ID too for the next level...

```
table: class_student_assn
index: (student_id, class_id )
```

Similar, student to match previous, and class to match the next

```
table: class
index: (id, class_status_id )
```

finally the class and it's status.

I would be interested in the results from this... and depending, I have another alternative to your query

Comment: This was so helpful. I added all but the first index `(grade, homework_date, id)` on `H` (because the table is 200M rows and that would take a long time). But I was able to get queries to return in ~1s! I also moved the `homework_date` clause to the much smaller `SHA` table.

Comment: I also learned a lot about how you think about indexes. Thanks for that. I would be curious the direction of your alternative query as well.

Comment: @Ryan, my alternate would have started with the CLASS table for the specific status as the primary criteria and filtering down to the students/classes and homework.  If you have 3k classes, but only 250 are status = 2 (or whatever), you are immediately ignoring ANY home work associated the other 2750 classes.

Comment: Ah, so I need to pay very close attention to the order of joins. Ideally smaller to larger tables, so that I filter out much of the larger tables right away.

Comment: @Ryan, not necessarily, but it helps to understand where the smaller granular data is expected.  If you can hone-in on that vs looking at everything in the universe down, you KNOW what you are looking for, do you have a way of pointing directly to that element and then back-peddle to get your other elements.  Hopefully make sense, and glad your under 1 second now.

Comment: @Ryan, one such example... You have a master table of Sales Order Details for example.  The orders have plenty of lookups to secondary tables such as order ID, itemID, order status code, etc...  If you start at the smaller order status code table back to the sales items, not necessarily efficient.  The core is the sales items.